# Spacy DependencyMatcher returning empty value

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

Code from the tutorial: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#dependencymatcher

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.matcher import DependencyMatcher
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()


matcher = DependencyMatcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [
    {
        "RIGHT_ID": "anchor_founded",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"ORTH": "founded"}
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "anchor_founded",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "founded_subject",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": "nsubj"},
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "anchor_founded",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "founded_object",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": "dobj"},
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "founded_object",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "founded_object_modifier",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": {"IN": ["amod", "compound"]}},
    }
]

matcher.add("FOUNDED", [pattern])
doc = nlp("Lee, an experienced CEO, has FOUNDED two AI startups.")
matches = matcher(doc)

print(matches)
```

Result I should get [(4851363122962674176, [6, 0, 10, 9])]
What I get is this []

**My Environment**

- spaCy version: 3.0.5
- Platform: Windows-10
- Python version: 3.6.13
- en_core_web_sm = 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using ORTH to find "founded". This is case-sensitive. You should either replace ORTH with LOWER, or simply lowercase FOUNDED in your input sentence

Comment: Thanks you Kris!